# dynamic menu with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am building the navigation menu it contains categories which will be pulled out from a database for instance

```
Home      + Product   
          - Ham
          - Sausage
          - etc 
          - etc 


--------Database Schema------
+----+-------------------------+------+
| id | name                    | show |
+----+-------------------------+------+
|  1 | ham                     |    1 |
|  2 | sausages                |    1 |
+----+-------------------------+------+
```

this is my Categories Controller

```
class Categories extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->load->model('category');
        }

        public function index()
        {   
            // 1. pulling data from db assigned to $data
            $data['categories'] = $this->category->get_categories();

            // 2. passing $data to header view to build dynamic navigation menu
            $this->load->view('header',$data);

            // 3. passing $data to the view category to render some other content
            $this->load->view('category',$data);

            // 4. passing $data to footer view to build dynamic footer menu
            $this->load->view('footer',$data);
         }


         public function get($id)
         {
            $this->load->view('header');


     } 
}
```

------------ views/header.php page   ( code as show below )

```
<ul>
   <?php foreach($categories as $item): ?>
   <li><a href="categories/get/<?php echo $item->id;?>"><?php echo $item->name;?></a></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

----------- Problem is 
when i choose a category from the menu for instance ham i see the url is like this

127.0.0.1/cms/categories/get/1   **this on the categories page**

and when i click for instance ham i will be transfer to this url

127.0.0.1/cms/categories/get/1

**but when i hover over the menu i see this**

**127.0.0.1/cms/categories/get/categories/get/1**  here is the problem with the nav menu

you see guys, the controller which is  {categories} as well as the action which is {get} 
each controller and action are repeated twice,

My questions 
1- what i am doing wrong in here -

2- how to share this dynamic menu through the entire application correctly, where should i put this code. and please also keep in mind this menu will be created from a database

thank you so much in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to fix the view

```
<ul>
   <?php foreach($categories as $item): ?>
   <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/get/<?php echo $item->id;?>"><?php echo $item->name;?></a></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

For loading it in view correctly... I suggest, you create a file call template in your view folder, lets call it template.php

```
public function index()
    {   
        // 1. pulling data from db assigned to $data
        $data['categories'] = $this->category->get_categories();

        $data['page_name'] = 'WHATEVER_PAGE_NAME_YOU_HAVE';

        // send it to the template instead....
        $this->load->view('template',$data);
     }
```

TEMPLATE FILE

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      $this->load->view('header');

      $this->load->view($data['page_name']);

      $this->load->view('footer');
   </body>
</html>
```

HEADER.PHP File will be like this ....

```
     <div>HEADER CONTENT </div>
```

WHATEVER_PAGE_NAME_YOU_HAVE.PHP File will be like this ....

```
    <h1>TESTING</h1>
```

FOOTER.PHP File will be like this ....

```
     <div>Footer CONTENT </div>
```

For keeping it more easy to manage, create library and call it in costructor of every class OR you can auto load it. Once its loaded, you can call the function and get your data.. let me know if you need an example? or you can read http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html
HOPE IT HELPS...

Answer (score 0):

I made a small library for this dynamic menu. If anyone still looking this answer, Hope this help for them.

You can grab this all code from Github.

```
https://github.com/hassann201/Egenius_Dynamic_Menu
```

Thanks